# Does a complex compact surface of general type have to be algebraic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact, complex surface with Kodaira dimension $2$, in other words a surface of general type.

A complex surface is called *algebraic* if has a (complex) embedding in $\mathbb{CP}^N$ for some $N$.

> Is $X$ algebraic?

It follows from Kodaira's embedding theorem that if $X$ admits an ample line bundle then is algebraic. However I don't see how to go from the definition of Kodaira dimension given in terms of plurigenera to the positivity/ampleness.

Comment: The Kodaira dimension is $\leq$ the transcendence degree of the field of meromorphic functions. So if $X$ is of general type, its field of meromorphic functions has transcendence degree $2$ and a classical theorem then says that $X$ is projective. See Barth et al., Compact Complex Surfaces, I.7.1 and IV.6.5 for all this.

Comment: @DamianRössler Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the statements in your question, a compact surface is assumed to be smooth.  However, we indeed have more singular version results in this direction.

**(Definition)** If a reduced irreducible complex space (not necessarily smooth) $X$ admits a big line bundle $L$, i.e., $\kappa(X,L)=\textit{dim}(X)$, then we say that $X$ is a *Moishezon variety*. Thus, a complex space $X$ which is of general type is a special  Moishezon variety as we just let $L=K_X$.

Here, the term “complex space" is in the analytic category. A complex analytic variety or complex analytic space is a generalization of a complex manifold which allows the presence of singularities. Complex analytic varieties are locally ringed spaces which are locally isomorphic to local model spaces, where a local model space is an open subset of the vanishing locus of a finite set of holomorphic functions. You can see Coherent Analytic Sheaves written by Grauert and Remmert for more details.

As Damian Rössler says, a smooth Moishezon surface is automatically projective/algebraic. Furthermore, in the *singular* world, Artin had a remarkable result, see [Some Numerical Criteria for Contractability of Curves on Algebraic Surfaces](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372985), namely, every normal Moishezon surface with at most rational singularities is projective. See [this page](https://pinakimondal.org/simplest-singularity-on-non-algebraic-normal-moishezon-surfaces/#art62) for more details.

Here is a quick approach to prove the claim a smooth Moishezon surface is automatically projective/algebraic. We say a compact complex manifold $X$ in the Fujiki class $\mathcal C$  if there exists a resolution/modification $\widetilde X \rightarrow X$ such that $\widetilde X$ is a compact Kaehler manifold. So, if $X$ is a Moishezon manifold, then it must be in the Fujiki class, since there also exists a criterion saying that compact complex manifold  is Moishezon if there exists a resolution/modification $\widetilde X \rightarrow X$ such that $\widetilde X$ is a projective manifold.

Now, we're going to prove that smooth Moishezon surface is projective. We need another criterion: Moishezon variety with at most rational singularities +Kahler=projective. For this result you can see Yoshinori Namikawa, Projectivity criterion of Moishezon spaces and density of projective symplectic varieties, Internat. J. Math. 13 (2002), 125–135. The final observation lies in that relying on the classification theory due to Kodaira, every smooth Moishezon (then in the Fujiki class) surface is Kahler. With all these things, the proof is complete.

Comment: What is a complex "space"? Do you mean an algebraic variety?
Also how do you prove that a Moishezon surface is projective ?

Comment: @Overflowian, this term is in the analytic category. A complex analytic variety or complex analytic space is a generalization of a complex manifold which allows the presence of singularities. Complex analytic varieties are locally ringed spaces which are locally isomorphic to local model spaces, where a local model space is an open subset of the vanishing locus of a finite set of holomorphic functions. You can see Coherent Analytic Sheaves written by Grauert and Remmert for more details.

Comment: @Overflowian, for your second question. Here is a quick approach. We say a compact complex manifold $X$ in the Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ if there exists a resolution/modification $\widetilde X\rightarrow X$ such that $\widetilde X$ is a compact Kaehler manifold. So, if $X$ is a Moishezon manifold, then it must be in the Fujiki class, since there also exists a criterion saying that compact complex manifold $X$ is Moishezon if there exists a resolution/modification $\widetilde X\rightarrow X$ such that $\widetilde X$ is a projective manifold.

Comment: Now, we're going to prove that smooth Moishezon surface is projective. We need another criterion: Moishezon variety with at most rational singularities +Kahler=projective. For this result you can see Yoshinori Namikawa, Projectivity criterion of Moishezon spaces and density of projective symplectic varieties, Internat. J. Math. 13 (2002), 125–135. The final observation  lies in that relying on the classification theory due to Kodaira, every smooth Moishezon (then in the Fujiki class) surface  is Kahler. With all these things, the proof is complete.

Comment: @Overflowian, I have to split my comments to several paragraphs due to word number limit. If you have any confusion, please feel free to comment:)

Comment: tipically in this cases one edits his answer :)

Comment: @Overflowian, okay! I've just added it.